# iOS: Keep real photo resolution when making screen capture with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: ios

I want to make a basic photo editing in my application and now I need to be able to add a text over a photo. Original photo have something like >2000 pixels width and height so it will be scaled to fit in screen without modifying its ratio.

So , I put the image in an UIImageView, dragged a Label over it and then save the image on screen with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext. The problem is I will get a small image (320 X some height).

What is the best approach to accomplish this task but not shrink the resolution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem in an app.

The thing I realised is that you can't do this by doing a screen capture. In turn, this means that dragging labels and text onto the image can't really be done (it can but bear with me) with UILabels etc...

What you need to do is keep a track of everything that's going on **data-wise**.

At the moment you have the `frame` of your `UIImageView`. This, in reality is irrelevant. It is purely there to show the user a representation of what is going on.

This is the same for the `UILabel`. It has a `frame` too. Again, this is irrelevant to the final image.

What you need is to store the data behind it in terms that are not absolute and then convert those values into frames for displaying on the device.

So, if you have an image that is `3200x4800` pixels (just making it easy for me) and this is displayed on the device and "shrunk" down to `320x480`. Now, the user places a label with a frame of `10, 10, 100, 21` with the text "Hello, world" at a particular font size.

Storing the frame `10, 10, 100, 21` is useless because what you need when the image is output is... `100, 100, 1000, 210` (i.e. ten times the size).

So, really you should be storing information in the background like...

```
frame = 0.031, 0.021, 0.312, 0.044
// these are all percentages
```

Now, you have percentage values of where the label should be and how big it should be based on the size of the image.

So, for the shrunk image size it will return `10, 10, 100, 21` and for the full image size it will be `100, 100, 1000, 210` and so will look the same size when printed out.

You could create a compound `UIView` by having a UIView with a UIImageView and a UILabel then you just have to resize it to the full image size before rendering it. That would be the easy but naive way of approaching it initially.

Or you could create a UIView with CALayers backing it that display the image and text.

Or you could render out the image and text with some sort of draw method.

Either way, you can't just use a screen capture.

And yes, this is a lot more complex than it first appears.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your well documented answer. Firstly I will try the first approach, the one with the view on the screen that has the real image size. I hope the font sizes are in arithmetic progressions , otherwise multiplying it with the shrunk scale won't work. I will come back with additional questions if I will be stuck.

Comment: @Meeshoo no worries. With the font size I had to create a loop of increasing font sizes and calculating the bounding rect (NSString function) until it got too big and then use the previous size.

Comment: The view containing the real sized image can be rendered with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext, too?

Comment: Are you receiving memory warning ? My app crashes with "Terminated due to Memory Pressure" error. The photo has ~ 2 mb after editing instead of 0.6 that has initially.